# detecting button press on a headset with two headsets attached?

Tags: android

If I have two sets of headsets plugged into one phone (using a headphone splitter), is there any way for the device to distinguish between the two when a button is pressed?

Each headset has a little button on it (and only one button) that can be detected by android. However, I am wondering if it was possible to determine which headset had it's button pressed.

From what I have seen at the moment, using `getSource()` or `getDeviceID()` on the key event yields the same result for either headset

edit - i've tried different headset models, but all the information is the same. Doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this would be possible with software, its more of a hardware problem, so what I am saying is no, I do not believe it is possible to do this because android sees it as the exact same thing from each head set.